# Equivalence Between the Algebras of the Standard Model and Connes Non-Commutative Geometry Model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, algebraic-geometry, non-commutative-geometry

I've been watching some lectures on Connes non commutative geometry model and one of the things I don't understand is why the algebra he considers, $M_2(\mathbb{H}) \oplus M_4(\mathbb{C})$, is equivalent to the standard model algebra $\text{u}(1) \otimes \text{su}(2) \otimes \text{su}(3)$. Why is it so? Another thing that was casually mentioned is that the automorphisms of the algebra correspond to the group of diffeomorphisms. How do I go about proving this? What's the intuition here, if there's any? If anyone could provide further references that explain these points in detail, I'd be thankful.